# Passing an aura:iterated list item to JS controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, javascript-controller, aura-iteration

The goal is to pass a "comment__c" rich text field on an iterated object to its JS  controller to perform a string operation on it before it's returned to limit a tooltip it is to appear into 250 characters. The console keeps printing truncString = [object Object] and I'm not sure if an object is getting passed and not a specific comment__c field or ?

*Component*

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.AddCommList}" var="item" indexVar="idx">
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
            <a onclick="{!c.handleClick}"><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!item.Name}">
                <lightning:formattedText value="{!item.Name}"/></div></a></th>
        <td>
            <div class = "slds-truncate" data-record = "{!idx}"
                <lightning:formattedRichText aura:id = "Comment__c"
                                             value = "{!item.c}"
                                             data-record = "{!idx}" />
            </div>
        </td>
```

*JS Controller*

```
showCommentTip : function(component, event, helper){
    var cmpTarget = component.find('commentInfo');
    $A.util.removeClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-fall-into-ground');
    $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-rise-from-ground');

    var selectedItem = event.currentTarget;
    var index = selectedItem.dataset.record;
    var truncString = component.get("v.AddCommList.Comment__c")[index];
    component.set('v.commentTooltip', truncString.substr(0, 250));
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect the code to look like this:

```
 var comment = component.get("v.AddCommList")[index].Comment__c;
 component.set('v.commentTooltip', comment.substr(0, 250));
```

The attribute holds the array, so once that is got you can index into it to get hold of a specific row. The row corresponds to an SObject and has a property available called `Comment__c`.